# Characteristic subgroups of a finite abelian $2$-group

Tags: gr.group-theory, finite-groups, abelian-groups

I have recently stumbled across the problem of describing the characteristic subgroups of a finite abelian group. With some discussions with some mathematicians in my lab, I managed to obtain a "visual" description of such, and wrote it down.

Nonetheless, I know that some of this work has already been clear by Kaplansky in "Infinite abelian groups". Combining both theorems 25 and 26, we obtain a description for every finite abelian $p$-group for $p\neq 2$, and then for every abelian finite group of odd order. I managed to obtain a (less aesthetical, but still understoodable) description for the finite abelian $2$-groups that Kaplansky mentions in the theorem 27 as problematic. In this book, I didn't manage to find some reference for such groups, but maybe some person here knows an article that has already tackles this question.

So my question is : has some text already given a reasonable parametrization of characteristic subgroups of finite abelian $2$-groups ?

Comment: Could you say something more about what your visual description looks like?

Comment: Kaplansky associate in substance somme function to any element and have a simple description of wich set of functions will give a fully invariant subgroup. I juste help myself from the visualization of the graph of this function and try to describe with few information the set of graphs that would give a characteristic subgroup.

Comment: It seems to me that there is the requisite description here Kerby, B. L., Rode, E. Characteristic Subgroups of Finite Abelian Groups. Communications in Algebra, 2011, 39:4, 1315-1343 (Section 2).

Comment: Thanks for this reference, which is what I looked for !

Comment: @kabenyuk you can maybe post it as answer so that I can mark it down.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems to me that there is the requisite description here Kerby, B. L., Rode, E. Characteristic Subgroups of Finite Abelian Groups. Communications in Algebra, 2011, 39:4, 1315-1343 (Section 2).

Theorem 2.9 describes characteristic subgroups of abelian 2-groups.